# How to run a emacs without loading `.emacs` nor `.emacs.d`?

Tags: macos, emacs

When I have a trouble with Emacs settings (that is quite often), I move setting directory and restart emacs.

But I think there is a better way to do it.

I'm using emacs 24 in osx. How can I launch Emacs without loading user settings?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `-q` option (alias for lets you invoke Emacs from the command line without running the startup script.

The other relevant options are:

```
--no-init-file, -q          load neither ~/.emacs nor default.el
--no-site-file              do not load site-start.el
--quick, -Q                 equivalent to -q --no-site-file --no-splash
```

On OS X, you can invoke Emacs like this:

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -Q ~/myfile.txt &
```